# Windows Server 2016 cannot load data from LDAP

Tags: ldap, windows-server-2016

we have following issue: we have LDAP server running on Linux, we have 2 windows servers .
Windows server 2016 and server windows 2012 . from server windows 2012 we can connect and load data from LDAP, from windows server 2016 we can connect, but fail to get data from LDAP.

I tested the connection with ping and got same results for both.

I thinks that we should install same ldap driver or provide some additional credentials.

in 2012 I use (from web browse )following URL LDAP://100.30.6.230:389/ou=People,dc=Main_1, and we get the users list.
but for same url in 2016 I get following message "There are no entries in the derectory service that match your search criteria".